# Batch deleting every file except partial files

Tags: batch-file, cmd, xcopy, del

I have a batch file, that constantly checks to see if there are any files in a directory:

```
    @echo off
    cls
    mode 15,5 
    cd C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\
    goto mark
:mark
    set var=2
    dir /b /a "Downloads\*" | >nul findstr "^" && (goto exin) || (goto mark1)
    goto mark
:mark1
    cls
    @ping -n 10 localhost> nul
    goto mark
:exin
    start /B C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Test\download.bat
    exit
```

if ther are any files in this folder, it moves them.

```
    @echo off
cls
cd C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Downloads        
        xcopy /Y C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Downloads\*.rar C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Archive
        xcopy /Y C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Downloads\*.zip C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Archive
        xcopy /Y C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Downloads\*.exe C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Setups_usw
        xcopy /Y C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Downloads\*.msi C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Setups_usw
        xcopy /Y C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Downloads\*.mp3 E:\-_MUSIC_-\Musik
        xcopy /Y C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Downloads\*.wav E:\-_MUSIC_-\Musik
        xcopy /S /E /Y /EXCLUDE:C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Test\excludedfileslist.txt C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Downloads\*.* C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Sonstiges
    goto err        
    :err
    if errorlevel 1 ( dir /arashd >> "C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Test\somefile.txt" 2>&1  ) else ( del /[!*.part] * )
    goto end
    :end
    start /B C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Test\run.cmd
    exit
```

However, I do not want to move files that are in the process of downloading (ie. I don't want to move partial files with a `.part` extension).

I tried using an argument to the `del` command like so:

```
del /[!*.part] *
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I avoid moving partial files with the `.part` extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably look at the file extension (using "substitution of FOR variables").

```
SET "TARGET_DIR=C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Downloads"
FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b "%TARGET_DIR%"') DO (
    REM  Ensure it doesn't have '.part' as an extension.
    IF NOT "%%~xf"==".part" (
        REM  Ensure there's not a corresponding ".part" file.
        IF NOT EXIST "%TARGET_DIR%\%%~f.part" (
            DEL "%TARGET_DIR%\%%~f"
        )
    )
)
```

This will delete any file in `TARGET_DIR` that doesn't have ".part" as a filename extension or have a corresponding ".part" file. (In my experience downloaders that do the ".part" thing also reserve the name of the "finished" file as well, which you'd probably not want to delete.)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @mojo, this your code I'll save for using it, for sure that is so a **normal** loop + **paranoiac** loop + 
  **psychopathic** loop!  So good, upv... Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution (shorter than @mojo's one):

```
@echo off
cd /d C:\Users\Toni\Downloads\Downloads
attrib +h *.part
for /f "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /b /A:-H') do del %%A
attrib -h *.part
```

This, will hide all `.part` files, delete all other files and remove again the hidden attribute.